# Expression.Call() to String.Equals() throws error

Tags: c#, linq

The following code:

```
var constant = Expression.Constant("find me", typeof(string));

// memberExpression evaluates to a string
var predicate = Expression.Call(memberExpression, "Equals", null, constant);
```

is throwing the error **More than one method 'Equals' on type 'System.String' is compatible with the supplied arguments**.

I'm guessing that's because there's `Equals(Object)` and `Equals(String)` - is there any way for me to specify which method I mean to use via the overload of `Expression.Call()` that takes an instance method name as a string?

Or do I have to make a special case for calls to `Equals()` to take a `MethodInfo` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass a `MethodInfo`.